# Configuring git repo - Ubuntu Server

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, deployment

I have started working on a project where the code at this moment is only on the ubuntu server. Site is big, it is a Magento based project. I am not sure how to proceed to configure it to use git.

Should I:

1. run git init on the server, add & commit, add server ssh key to github, add remote to the repo and push all? then just create a cron to run pull everynow and then?
2. Download site, handle repo locally, add & commit, add server ssh key to github, add remote to the repo and push all. Then how I would update server code?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, use a [`.gitignore` for Magento](https://www.gitignore.io/api/magento) (or [Magento2](https://www.gitignore.io/api/magento2)): that will give you what to add.

Second, as a general best practice, don't add private information (like a *private* ssh key) to a Git repo. [Magento2 manual says as much](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/cloud/env/environments-ssh.html).

Third, you can follow the general workflow described in [Magento GitHub integration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/cloud/project/project-integrate-github.html) for project update.